# Based on the spinner selection display the ListView

Tags: java, android

I have create a spinner when i select a option E.G:"Asset No" display the data using Asset no or if i select "Serial No" then it has to display the data using serial no

I have tried using Radio Group and it display the data but now i want it to spinner.

MainActivity Class

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    radiogroup = findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
    radio_assert =  findViewById(R.id.radio_assert);
    radio_serial = findViewById(R.id.radio_serial);
    searchview=  findViewById(R.id.searchview);



    listview = findViewById(R.id.listview);
    ArrayList list = getListData();
    Adapter = new ListAdapter(this, list);
    listview.setAdapter(Adapter);



    radiogroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new 
    RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)
    {
    switch(checkedId)
    {
    case R.id.radio_assert:
    adapter.getFilter().filter("ASSET");
    break;
    case R.id.radio_serial:
    adapter.getFilter().filter("SERIAL");
    break;
    }
    }
    });



    searchview.setOnQueryTextListener(new 
    SearchView.OnQueryTextListener()
    {
     @Override
     public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s)
     {
     Adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
     return true;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s)
     {
     Adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
     return true;
     }
     });
     }



     private ArrayList getListData()
     {
     ArrayList<ListItem> results = new ArrayList<>();
     ListItem l1 = new ListItem();
     l1.setNo("ASS001");
     l1.setType("ASSET");
     l1.setMake("LG");
     l1.setModel("Y9");
     results.add(l1);

     ListItem l2 = new ListItem();
     l2.setNo("ASS002");
     l2.setType("ASSET");
     l2.setMake("SAMSUNG");
     l2.setModel("Y5");
     results.add(l2);

     ListItem l3;
     l3 = new ListItem();
     l3.setNo("SE001");
     l3.setType("SERIAL");
     l3.setMake("OOPO");
     l3.setModel("Y1");
     results.add(l3);

     ListItem l4 = new ListItem();
     l4.setNo("SE002");
     l4.setType("SERIAL");
     l4.setMake("VIVO");
     l4.setModel("VI5");
     results.add(l4);
     return results;
     }
```

ListAdapter Class

```
     public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable 
     {
     private ArrayList<ListItem> listData;
     private ArrayList<ListItem> listFilteredData;
     private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;


    public ListAdapter(Context aContext, ArrayList<ListItem> listData) {
    this.listData = listData;
    this.listFilteredData = listData;
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(aContext);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
    return listFilteredData.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
    return listFilteredData.get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
    }
    public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup vg) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (v == null) {
        v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.no = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_row_no);
        holder.make = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_row_make);
        holder.model = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_row_model);
        v.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }
    holder.no.setText(listFilteredData.get(position).getNo());
    holder.make.setText(listFilteredData.get(position).getMake());
    holder.model.setText(listFilteredData.get(position).getModel());
    return v;
    }

   @Override
   public Filter getFilter() {
   return new Filter() {
   @Override
   protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
       FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
       if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
           results.count = listData.size();
           results.values = listData;
            }
            else
            {
                ArrayList<ListItem> resultsData = new ArrayList<>();
                ArrayList<ListItem> resultsData1 = new ArrayList<>();
                String searchStr = constraint.toString();

                if(searchStr.equalsIgnoreCase("assert")) {
                    for (ListItem o : listData)
                        if (o.getType().equalsIgnoreCase(searchStr)) 
             resultsData.add(o);
                } else if(searchStr.equalsIgnoreCase("serial")) {
                    for (ListItem o : listData)
                        if (o.getType().equalsIgnoreCase(searchStr)) 
             resultsData.add(o);
                } else
                    {
                    resultsData = listData;
                }

                for (ListItem o : resultsData)
                    if (o.getNo().contains(searchStr)) 
             resultsData1.add(o);

                if(resultsData1.size() == 0)
                    resultsData1 = resultsData;

                results.count = resultsData1.size();
                results.values = resultsData1;
            }
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, 
        FilterResults results) {
            listFilteredData = (ArrayList<ListItem>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
              }
           };
        }
        static class ViewHolder {
        TextView no;
        TextView make;
        TextView model;
          }
        }
```

ListItem Class

```
        public class ListItem {

        private String no;
        private String type;
        private String make;
        private String model;

        public ListItem() {
        }

        public ListItem(String no, String type, String make, String 
        model) {
          this.no = no;
          this.type = type;
          this.make = make;
          this.model = model;
          }
        public String getType() {
        return type;
        }
        public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
        }
        public String getNo() {
        return no;
        }
        public void setNo(String no) {
        this.no = no;
        }
        public String getMake() {
        return make;
        }
        public void setMake(String make) {
        this.make = make;
        }
        public String getModel() {
        return model;
        }
        public void setModel(String model) {`enter code here`
        this.model = model;
               }
        }
```

Expected Output is to if i select AssetNo in the spinner then in the listview it should display the details using AssetNo or if i select Serial No then it should display in the listview using Serilno.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to implement a Spinner (akin to how you implemented the radiogroup).
When you have the spinner set up, you can use the OnItemSelectedListener as a replacement to OnCheckedChangeListener that you used for the radiogroup.

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        ListItem item = list.get(position)
        adapter.getFilter().filter(item.getType());
    }

    @Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
        // your code here
    }
});
```

You can use the position in onitemSelected to figure out which item was selected. For example, if your spinner uses a list of items, you can use that list and access the item at the position given bby onItemSelected to get your currently selected item.

Hopefully that helps you a bit on your way.

Comment: I'm new to Android so can you please explain me with the coding then it will more helpful to understand for the above scenario @Rudy

Comment: How about you start with implementing the Spinner.
You managed to implement a radiogroup, a spinner is not much harder and there are tons of tutorials and guides on how the spinner works.
If you still have questions after that, I will be happy to answer them :)

Comment: I have seen some tutorial but those are when they select an option in the spinner then it's display the same one in the listview but my  question is to if i select Asset No then it has display the data using Asset No. or if i select Serial No then it has to display the data using Serial No.

Comment: I edited the code to make it a bit more complete, does this help?

Comment: No, Now in the spinner it's display only one option. :(

Comment: But this code does not change the spinner itself, only what the spinner does when an item is selected.
Maybe you need to review your spinner code?

Comment: I will check with my code and let you know about this issue.

Comment: If my answer and comments helped, please accept it as the answer for this post.